# How should assign user input from a read to a memory using scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
;; Create an empty memory
(define (make-mem) '())

;; Associate id with value in a memory
(define (mem-put mem id value)
  (if (null? mem)
      (list (list id value))
      (let ((pair (car mem))
            (rest (cdr mem))
            )
        (if (eq? id (car pair))
            (cons (list id value) rest)
            (cons pair (mem-put rest id value))))))

(define (exec-stmt stmt mem)
  (display stmt) (newline)
  (cond ((eq? (car stmt) 'display) (exec-display stmt mem))
        ((eq? (cadr stmt) ':=) (mem-put mem (car stmt) (caddr stmt)))
        ((eq? (car stmt) 'input) (exec-input (cdr stmt) (read) mem))
        (else (error "Jelle Error---Bad Statement:" stmt))))

(define (exec-input stmt inputs mem)
  (if (equal? (length inputs) 1)
      (mem-put mem stmt inputs)
      (exec-input (cdr stmt) (cdr inputs) (mem-put mem (car stmt) (car inputs)))))
```

Here we are making a memory data type which is a list. To assign variables to memory locations we are using mem-put. In exec-stmt if there an input in a stmt then we are calling exec-input and allowing user input. In exec-input when the user input is being passes, it is not returning a list and so length can't be called on it. We are using the length =1 as the base case since car and cdr can't be called on a list of one. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you use this code? btw A list of size one you can do `car` and `cdr` on. Its the empty list `()` you cannot use as a pair.

Comment: If you had a problem recursing on list structure, it was not due to the size of the list. You can use the `pair?` predicate to check whether something is a pair, and you might want to test `(list (read))` and see what happens.

Comment: "To assign variables to memory locations we are using `mem-put`" It's usually helpful to try each function in the repl as you go: `exec-input` uses `mem-put`, but if you just make a "memory", `mem-put` an item, and then view the memory, are you getting the result you expect?

Comment: `mem-put` has no side effect. You probably better use [hash-tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html).